# How to accept Apple Music Family invite without iOS/macOS?

Tags: itunes, apple-music, family-sharing

A couple of days ago I upgraded my Apple Music subscription to family mainly so my sisters could access music from their iPhones. Since my dad is avid music listener I decided to set up Apple Music for him also on his Windows laptop.

I sent the invite via email and then we created an Apple ID for him with this same email address. But there seems to be no way how to accept this invite without owning Apple device or at least Android one. This seems odd since iTunes is basically the Apple Music for macOS/Windows.

In my family sharing settings I still see the invite as sent and when I open iTunes on his Windows machine there is no indication that there is Apple Music family invite.

Have I missed anything or is this simply impossible?

**EDIT: I found a solution.** I created new user account on my Mac, signed in with dad's Apple ID and the Family Sharing invitation popped right up. iTunes on Windows now works fine.

Still would be nice to know if it is possible to accept invitation without Mac or spare iOS device..

Comment: Did you set up and sign into iCloud for Windows on your fathers machine?

Comment: @Allan I tried to.. but after trying to login with his Apple ID it told me to first setup iCloud on Apple device to have access to it.

Comment: Try setting up an iCloud email account via Outlook or some other mail client first.  Then try setting up iCloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you'll want to find a spare iOS device for your father's account to log in and accept the invitation. (or backup / wipe / set up your device for him - then wipe / restore your backup so that you don't mix streams of data signing out and then signing in as his account).

This would clearly be a bug and something you might be able to call Apple Support to see if they can push an alternate way to authenticate your father to the group.

My guess is the account is either blocked and needs apple push notification to tie it to a physical device one time and then it will work from windows. I've done this a handful of times for people that primarily are on Windows without needing to engage official support.

Comment: Thanks, wiping my iPhone seems rather drastic measure. Just tried Xcode simulator but didn't work. What about temporary account on my Macbook? Would that work?

Comment: @Filip Yes - I'd try to find a loaner device or another account on your Mac. Much easier to clean up and less time. You could probably find an iPhone 6 for cheap and put a $29 official battery in it if that's something that might help your father with the music and managing his iCloud account.

Answer (score 0):

As for 2022, Apple Music or iTunes seems to support accepting invitations on Windows or Android.

I have tried accepting invitation on my Android device. Then Apple sent an email to me with a "get start" link. What I have to do next is to open this link with Apple Music application. If on Windows, the case should be opening with iTunes application.